# Search multiple field form data in mysql database with python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

How do i write a query if the multiple form field data are being searched in mysql database.

The form fields are as follow

```
FirstName:
LastName:
Age:
Gender:
```

Now we can enter data in any multiple field and make a search
the code i have tried works for single field. Unable to create for multiple conditions

```
sql = "select * from PERSON where F_Name = %s or L_Name = %s or Age = %s and Gender = %s" 
self.cursor.execute(sql,(self.fname, self.lname, self.age, self.gender))
```

If field FirstName and Gender are filled

If field Lastname, Gender, age are filled

If field FirsName, Age are filled

If field Gender and lastname are filled

like all possible conditions

Comment: Please dont add the same question again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970937/search-in-mysql-database-with-multiple-field-in-a-form-with-python

Comment: I think It's third time you asked this question in past 24 hours

Comment: I am not getting the reply...sorry for but...its kind of important to me and deadline for me

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i write multiple conditions in single sql query to get data - Python mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952356/how-do-i-write-multiple-conditions-in-single-sql-query-to-get-data-python-mysq)

Comment: No..I am not getting that stuff too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not python or any language specific. This is about query syntax.

Try this

`sql = "select * from PERSON where (F_Name = '%s' or L_Name = '%s' or Age = '%s') and Gender = '%s';" 
self.cursor.execute(sql % (self.fname, self.lname, self.age, self.gender))`

Refer this http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/9/3/13

Comment: do it fulfill all the condition ? i can enter data in any field and can make a search ?  does it work that way ?

Comment: It doesn't work as expected. It satisfies only certain conditions

Comment: add ' before and after of each %s.

Comment: Your output query like this
"select * from PERSON where (F_Name = 'first_name' or L_Name = 'last_name' or Age = '23') and Gender = 'male';"

And make sure Age is string or integer.

Comment: Age is a string. And all my data are coming from the form, so its dynamic

Comment: Then what was the output you got?

Comment: I think your query doesn't match with any row. Can you check this?